# how to filter 10 objects with maximum column value in django using postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my model.

```
class Score(models.Model):
   overall_score = models.FloatField('Overall Score')
```

I want to get 10 objects of class Score whose overall_score is maximum.

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? This is **really** straightforward, provided you [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: i tried using Max. But it only gives 1 object with maximum column value. I would like to fetch 10 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [order by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) `overall_score` descending, than take top ten records using [slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

```
Score.objects.order_by("-overall_score")[:10]
```

Refer to [official Django documentation on QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for details.

Please, research the documentation before asking. Don't turn `python` into `php` where the questions thoroughly answered in official documentation and on stackoverflow arise again and again.